# Escaping colon in SQL DELETE LIKE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to delete all rows in which the second column contains the hour 23:59:00.

```
int      datetime
|1 |          2       |
125 2010-12-27 00:00:00
120 2011-12-27 00:00:00
84  2012-12-26 00:00:00
108 2013-12-26 00:00:00
139 2013-12-26 23:59:00
73  2014-12-26 00:00:00
140 2014-12-26 23:59:00
```

I have tried the command

```
DELETE FROM Something
WHERE Date LIKE '%23:59:00'
```

But it isn't working. Do I have to escape the colon or should I just find another way of identifying the rows?

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Comment: The typename is 'datetime' using SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
...WHERE DATEPART(hh, [date]) = 23 AND DATEPART(mi, [date]) = 59
```

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258265%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I got 'HOUR' is not a recognized built-in function name. As far as I'm aware the database is in SQL Server.

Comment: You could try the DATEPART() function e.g. DATEPART(hh, date), DATEPART(mm, date)

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO my fault.

Answer (score 2):

One choice:

```
Where DatePart( hh, [date] ) = 23 And DatePart( mi, [date] ) = 59
```

If you are using SQL Server 2008 or later

```
Where Cast( [date] As Time ) >= '23:59:00'
```

[DatePart function.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use LIKE, cast datetime as string, ex.

> CONVERT(varchar,date,120) like '%23:59:00'